# Prevent network weights to be updated when performing backward pass

Tags: machine-learning, conv-neural-network, torch, backpropagation

I am trying to perform a backward pass through my network and I don't want to update my network weights of my network when, I do a backward pass.

```
output = net:forward(input)
err = criterion:forward(output, label)
df_do = criterion:backward(output, label)
net:backward(input, df_do)
```

I'm assuming this can be done using by any of the two methods

```
accGradParameters(input, gradOutput, scale)
accUpdateGradParameters(input, gradOutput, learningRate)
```

Can,I do this using the optim package in torch?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finetune a Torch model](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37459812/finetune-a-torch-model)

Comment: This is not a duplicate, I know about finetuning a network.However, I would like to perform backpropogation without updating the weights for a network